# Can I build an IM Service client like GTalk in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i'm developing an app for people with communication disease. The point is that in my app i need that the user uses his gmail account to chat with his friends, like gmail gtalk service with helps to create the message.

I read the XMPP service of GAE but it only permit communication between an user and my app, not between users.

I tried with Smack Api but GAE doesn't suppor it.

I can create a chat with the Channel Service, but if i want to support Instant Messaging between two users is needed that an user make his account and his friends has to do it too to create the IM interface, and has to uses my web interface not a jabber client like Gtalk.

Can is communicate two users with XMPP in GAE, making an IM like GTalk?

Comment: Why don't you set up an XMPP server?

Comment: Thanks, which one i could set up in GAE?

Comment: Why do you want to do this on GAE?  Most XMPP servers use some sort of SQL backend for the user database, so you'll have to rebuild that for GAE.  You're better off on AWS or Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [Google Cloud Messaging Service](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging.html).
The service just introduced last year and they just announced a lot of enhancement during the Google I/O 2013.

It supports messaging from/to browser, android, and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go with something like [OpenFire RTC Server](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) that is based on XMPP standards. This will help get you a XMPP Server running in no time and as suggested, you could look at hosting this on something like EC2.

A related thread : https://serverfault.com/questions/229039/xmpp-server-on-ec2-amazon-web-service-aws